# Collider Trigger and Movement

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a tower defense style game. I have a player gameobject  with a sphere collider, and turrets firing projectiles at it. The projectiles have capsule colliders. When the player game object is moving, the `OnTriggerEnter` events fire for the colliders of the projectile. When the player is not moving, they do not. The same goes for when I add new turrets. The turrets have a large sphere collider to determine if a game object is close enough to shoot at. When I add a new turret to a scene while playing, the `OnTriggerEnter` does not occur until I move the player game object, even though it is already within the sphere collider of the turret.

video: http://screencast.com/t/x1QKtNEK

How can I work around this? I doubt this is a bug, just my lack of understanding the Unity update, or something to do with collider triggers.

Comment: [I had a similar problem](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70036/strange-collision-behaviour-in-2d-game-even-though-the-collision-is-very-basic). Does your game object have a rigid body attached to it? Or the projectiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug, but [unity's documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) states that

> "OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for every Collider
>   other that is touching the trigger."

Maybe same applies `OnTriggerEnter` and "almost" is the problem here.

Do you have rigidbody on at least other part of the collision? Same documentation (and `OnTriggerEnter` documentation) also states that

> "Note that trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also
>   has a rigidbody attached".

Hopefully you find a proper solution to the problem, but as a workaround you could try to set player's collider into a child `GameObject` and move it little on every frame. If you don't have anything rendering related on the child `GameObject` no one will notice the hack.

Or projectiles can be handled with just calculating the distance to the player in their update function. Turrets can do the same calculation in their start function.

Comment: I added a rigid body to the projectile and that fixed the issue with the trigger when the object was not moving. Thank you. I did notice an immediate degradation of performance seen by the movement of the projectile (jittery, jumpy, inconsistent). I set the 'is Kinematic' on the rigid body and that seems to have fixed the performance. This did not fix the issue with new turret placement and the firing of OnTriggerEnter. This appears to be a separate issue. I'll follow up or write a separate question on stack.

Comment: Is there a rigid body in either on the player or on the turret? It seems that at least other one of those has to have rigid body to fix the turret problem.